# iOS: apple universal link if app is not open?

Tags: ios

My app can successfully handle apple universal links, if the app is already open (backgrounded). But if the app is not open already, then when I tap such a link in, say, mail, the app opens, but I never get the callback for application:continueUserActivity... (which I do if the app was already open/backgrounded)...

To wit:

If the app is backgrounded, and I click on an apple universal link in, say, the mail app, then this method (which is what apple's documentation says to implement to handle universal links):

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication,
     continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity,
       restorationHandler restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

Gets called. If the app is not running (I force close it), then when I click on the link, that method does NOT get called, but the app DOES open.

Is this supposed to work this way?

---

Based MCMatan's clue, you have to do something like this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and then continueUserActivity will get called:

```
if let userActivityDict = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey] as? NSDictionary,
      activityType = userActivityDict[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityTypeKey] as? String where activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {

    return true
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post your code and explain a little more thoroughly in order for us to help you out ;)

Comment: @brandonscript I thought it was perfectly clear, but I added more anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. If the app is not in background "continueUserActivity" will not be called.

Instead, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will call with the information:

```
let activityDic = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey]
if let isActivityDic = activityDic {
    // Continue activity here
}
```

Comment: continueUserActivity is called even if app is not in background. When app opens up application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called, then  continueUserActivity is also called

Comment: Not being called in my case

Comment: continueUserActivity is only firing for me if the app is in the background