# Universal links don't call NSUserActivity to receive data

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with universal links, the problem is that the method `userActivity: NSUserActivity` for receiving the link information is not called if the app is not open or in the background.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751990/ios-apple-universal-link-if-app-is-not-open), but I do not know exactly how to implement it since it is not specified.

Comment: this method get called - func application(_ application: UIApplication, willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String) -> Bool

Comment: thanks rishi, but not call when no running, I need the method userActivity, because the link:  https://domine/dataiNeedDynamic   is  dynamic.